# Take off a small 1x1 piece from bigger LEGO surface

Tags: disassembly

**In general, what is the best approach to take off small pieces from a surface like the one in the picture?**

[image]

#### How to proceed

What should I do if

- I don't want to deal any damage to LEGO itself?
- I want to take it off as soon as possible?
- I want to do it in the simplest way possible?

Comment: to use [this beloved thingy](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9516/is-there-a-tool-that-can-consistently-remove-hundreds-of-2x2-tiles/9517#9517)

Comment: I would also suggest [this](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/444/132) technique, it doesn't involve scratching the underside of the plate and it doesn't have to be this exact piece.

Comment: I just use my thumb nail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any part that has a stud on the surface can be fairly easily removed by using leverage from a different large part added to the top of it. This takes advantage of the inherent "clutch power" of the stud/anti-stud connection and the increased surface area of the larger part to concentrate the force used to remove the part in a lateral direction.

For example, by placing a 1x6 plate over the trans-yellow 1x1 plate and then pushing the 1x6 plate away from the trans-orange plate will likely pull the trans-yellow plate up fairly easily.

LEGO also produces a purpose built tool called the [Brick Separator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=96874) that uses both that technique as well as giving additional leverage by pushing the part with the under or over-hanging ledge on the top and bottom of the front of the tool.

Answer (score -2):

so take a thin lego piece and use it to make the small piece fly off

Comment: How would you use it? Could you provide a description, illustration or photo?